# Gesture Recognizer memory usage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am adding several different swipe gestures to my app and I'm wondering if it would be better to just add one and query it for how many fingers, direction, etc.

By adding several distinct gesture recognizers up front (each with different swipe direction and number of required touches) I can easily route each to its own handler method and deal with them independently.

Do these UIGestureRecognizer objects take a lot of memory?

Comment: What does the profiler say?

Comment: can't check just now since i'm working on a simulator which does not work with profiling

Comment: unless you are struggling for memory, i wouldnt worry about it. im pretty sure it doesnt use a lot compared to say, an image or something bulkier.